# Maintaining Operation Id Through a Request in Web API

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api2

It is not uncommon in a RESTful setting for the client to sent an operation id (typically a GUID) so that the request logs can be traced.

My question is, in Web API, is there a way native to .NET Web API to track the id per request?

log4net has LogicalContext that could track that. The problem with LogicalContext is that it is specific to log4net and cannot be used with NLog. There is no way in LogicalContext to get the list of all keys. I have to know the key before hand, which cases a problem if one API calls it "operation id" and another API calls it "activity id".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the Guid 'Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId' for CorrelationId ?

It can be configured per request in your application-class (inherits from System.Web.HttpApplication) using the method Application_BeginRequest.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Thank you. There is a problem however: Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId does not seem to be consistent. If in a request I set ActivityId to be a certain value, and during the request I instantiate multiple threads, then all of a sudden the value of ActivityId in these threads are not equal, while LogicalThreadContext in log4net is consistent across multiple threads.

Comment: @Husain NLog has MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext (MDLC) when the async logical context moves between threads. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer